# The project wasn't generated by 'android' tool. Error in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, ide, intellij-idea

I've been struggling with an error with IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4 when creating a new Android project.

I've tried all the possible solutions that I found online but never ran into any solution.

On the console panel it says **"The project wasn't generated by 'android' tool."**

First error while creating an Android Project :

> http://s9.postimg.org/m0lyq2pzz/image.png

This is the warning that shows up after the first alert:

> http://s15.postimg.org/gorcjvkbf/image.png
>   `

However with the Eclipse, I can create an Android project (using the same SDK setup with IntelliJ and there are no errors.)

Also, when I import the project that I create in Eclipse previously, IntelliJ works just fine!

What could be IntelliJ's exact problem?

Answer (score 0):

OK I solved it. It was Comodo Antivirus firewall. You may add some exceptions for adb.exe for the solution. but I uninstalled the whole AV.

Hope this helps those who have the same problem.